# Is there a way to clean MySQL BinLog files if MySQL is off

Tags: mysql, digital-ocean

I am using an Ubuntu server to host a Wordpress website. The last few days, MySQL Bin files have been too much and they have filled up my storage.

The solutions I see online require running a purge command from MySQL. The issue is since my storage is full, Apache2 and MySQL are off and I am unable to run the command through MySQL.

There are more than 30 Binlog files and they are more than 1GB each in the folder

```
/var/lib/mysql
```

The command:

```
df -H --output=source,size,used,avail
```

returns:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail
tmpfs           412M   43M  370M
/dev/vda1        63G   63G     0
tmpfs           2.1G     0  2.1G
tmpfs           5.3M     0  5.3M
/dev/vda15      110M  5.5M  104M
tmpfs           412M  4.1k  412M
```

How can I clear the storage and keep my data intact.
Please help.

Comment: What version of MySQL

Comment: It is Version 8

Answer (score 1):

What are the binlogs used for, they contain information about changes made to the database since the last backup.

So, as I assume your database does not need recovering, you could manually move (or delete) a number of these binlog.0000x files all but the most recent one.

Then edit the `binlog.index` file removing the reference to all the files you have removed or deleted.

Then start MySQL, but **not** the web server, run a backup, as the system is down anyway, a few more minutes wont hurt

purge the logfiles normally,

```
PURGE BINARY LOGS TO 'binlog.0000??';   add the latest file number
```

You now have a consistent database and after-look recovery (binlog) file set ready to continue. And a backup to restore if needed.

You now have some time to work out why you had this sudden surge in logfile size, so you can work out what you need to do in the future to cope with this